# javascript generating random characters

Tags: javascript

I am trying to program a password generator. However, I find that my code is unreliable. I want each run of my function to return 20 random characters. This works most times, however if I spam the function enough times then I sometimes get a result that's below my criteria (eg: 2 strings, none, etc).

```
var longth = 20,
allc = "!@#$%^&*()_+~`|}{[]\:;?><,./-=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
passgen = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < longth; i++) {
    passgen += allc.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * allc.length));
  }
```

Not sure if the problem is with logic in my code, or if there's a break in one of the characters in my `allc` variable that's causing problems. Maybe I'm not expressing the variable correctly.

Comment: what do you mean? Are you sure this won't work?

Comment: what are your criteria?

Comment: *"I sometimes get a result that's below my criteria (eg: 2 strings, none, etc)"* - Huh? The code shown produces one string, so what do you mean by "2 strings", none, etc"? Can you please [edit] your question to add some examples of the incorrect results?

Comment: meant to say 'characters'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem with your code. I have modified it slightly to take a direct index out of the array, rather than using `charAt` but that shouldn't matter.

**This code is tested by creating 1,000,000 strings** and logs how many failed the creation criteria. **It doesn't seem to fail.**

```js
function makePassword(){
  var longth = 20,
  allc = "!@#$%^&*()_+~`|}{[]\:;?><,./-=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
  passgen = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < longth; i++) {
    passgen += allc[Math.floor(Math.random() * allc.length)];
  }
  return passgen;
}

// Test
var failed = [];
var result = "";
for(var x = 0; x < 1000000; ++x){
  result = makePassword();
  if(result.length !== 20){
    failed.push(result);
  }
}

console.log("Incorrect strings generated: " + failed.length, failed);
```